# Can a function be a norm even if it is non-zero for every input?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $V\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a vectorspace and $A: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear function. The operator norm of $A$ is defined as
$$
\|A\|=\sup_{x\in V\setminus \{0\}} \frac{\|A(x)\|_V}{\|x\|_V}\overset{?}{=}\sup_{x\in V, \|x\|=1} \|A(x)\|_V
$$

I don't understand why it is considered a norm because $\|A\|=\sup_{x\in V\setminus \{0\}} \frac{\|A(x)\|_V}{\|x\|_V}=0$ is not possible unless $A=0$ but $x$ is the input and $x=0$ is not allowed. If I proof that something is a norm, I thought that I always need to consider the case $\|A\|=0$. I don't necessarily see a contradiction here, if a norm $\|\dot\|$ is never zero, then that's not a violation of positive definiteness.
Can a function be a norm even if it is non-zero for every input?

In my case $A$ is a matrix, so $A: V\to V, x\mapsto A\cdot x$. $\|A\|=\sup_{x\in V\setminus \{0\}} \frac{\|A\cdot x\|_V}{\|x\|_V}$.
What I find a bit odd is that the norm is not necessarily defined because $V$ could be an unlimited set. So $x\in V$ could be chosen to be arbitrarily large in this case and the entries of $A$ are finite, so the norm of $\|A\cdot x\|$ could become infintly large, i.e. there is no supremum.

Comment: It is the norm of $A$ and not the norm of $x$. And in fact, $\|A\|=0$ if and only if $A=0$.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  As noted above, $\|A\| = 0$ if and only if $A = 0$.  This is a *requirement* for a norm (i.e. it is only zero on the zero element).  And in your last expression, I believe you mean $\|x\|=1$, not $\|v\|=1$ (otherwise, where is $v$ used?).

Comment: I really suspect that the confusion comes from the fact that it is an *operator* norm and not a *vector* norm. Also, note that while $\|Ax\|$ could be come arbitrarily large, it is not the case of $\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}$ (at leas in finite dimensions).

Comment: @Surb Yes, exactly. I'm sorry I phrased my question so poorly. The norm-function is $ \| .\|: \{A: V\to V | A \text{ linear } \}\to \mathbb{R}\cup \infty$. I should've written it down like that to avoid confusion.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: I misunderstood the operator norm. My question has been clarified because I now understand better what the definition is. The exact definition of the operator norm was not in my script and I am guided by what is written there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are missing is that the operator norm acts on linear maps $V\to V$, rather than on elements of $V$. That is, if $V$ is finite-dimensional real vector space, then the operator norm is a map $\lVert \cdot\lVert_{\text{op}}:\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}\Hom(V)\to\mathbb R$, where $\Hom(V)$ denotes the set of linear maps from $V$ to $V$; thus, the operator norm takes in a linear map as its input, and spits out a real number. Note that $\Hom(V)$ is itself a real vector space under pointwise addition and scalar multiplication.

As you say, the operator norm can be defined in two equivalent ways: for each $A\in\Hom(V)$,
$$
\lVert A\lVert_{\text{op}}=\sup_{x\in V\setminus\{0\}}\frac{\lVert A(x)\rVert_{V}}{\lVert x\rVert_V}=\sup_{x\in V\setminus\{0\},\lVert x\rVert =1}\lVert A(x)\rVert \, .
$$
To show that the operator norm is indeed a *norm*, you first need to recall that if $W$ is a real vector space, then a *norm on $W$* is a map $\lVert\cdot\rVert:W\to\mathbb R$ satisfying various axioms, e.g. to say that $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ is positive definite means that if $\lVert w\rVert=0$ then $w=0$. Note that the statement $w=0$ means that $w$ equals the additive identity of the vector space $W$, so the fact that $W$ has a vector space structure is crucial here.

The operator norm is a *norm on $\Hom(V)$*. To say that it is positive definite, for instance, means that if $\lVert A\rVert =0$ then $A=0$, where $0$ denotes the zero map $V\to V$. This is the “zero” of the vector space $\Hom(V)$.